# A Fair Dice is Rolled. Find the Expected Value of the Roll.

Tags: expectation

This method is used from the expectation of a discrete variable. Would this be right?

E(X) = (1 * 1/6) + (2 * 1/6) + (3 * 1/6) + (4 * 1/6) + (5 * 1/6) + (6 * 1/6)

E(X) = 1/6 (1+2+3+4+5+6)

E(X) = 21 / 6

E(X) = 7 / 2

Comment: Yes, that's correct.